# XSLT 2.0: regex in Saxon vs. XMLSpy

Tags: xml, regex, xslt-2.0

I have XMLSpy complaining about this:

`regex="url\(\"\.\./([^\"]*)\"\)"`  (outer quotes are double)

It says that the first backslash in `\.\.` is unexpected.

So I change it to:

`regex='url\(\"\.\./([^\"]*)\"\)'`  (single outer ticks)

And all is well.

but then Saxon complains: `XTDE1140: char 7 in regular expression: Escape character '"' not allowed.` So that is the first ".

Apparently, Altova and Saxonica are not on the same page. Any suggestions?

btw.: it's about a string like `url("../Fonts/bodoni.ttf")`. I need to strip the `../` out of it.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to escape double quote characters in a regular expression:

```
regex='url\("\.\./([^"]*)"\)'
```

(with single quotes around the attribute value) will work just fine.

The only restriction you need to be aware of is the XML one that you can't use double quote characters inside double quoted attributes, or single quote characters inside single quoted attributes, unless they are escaped as `&quot;` or `&apos;` respectively (or equivalent numeric character references).

Answer (score 0):

Ow, I found it:
 I must use `&quot;`:

`regex="url\(&quot;\.\./([^&quot;]*)&quot;\)"`